# How to import generated source in dart2 using build_runner?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-2

I want to create a `Builder` that would create `Env` class on the fly. That class should be available for import anywhere in my project. It is as container for environment constants defined in `build.yml`

Builder itself works fine, it generates desired output, however when I run

```
pub run build_runner build
```

build fails with following message

> [SEVERE] build_web_compilers:entrypoint on web/main.dart: Unable to
>   find modules for some sources, this is usually the result of either a
>   bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or possibly a
>   dev_dependency needs to move to a real dependency), or a build failure
>   (if importing a generated file).
>
> Please check the following imports:
>
> `import
>   '../.dart_tool/build/generated/buildertest/lib/environment.g.dart';`
>   from buildertest|web/main.dart at 2:1
>
> [INFO] Running build completed, took 4.1s [INFO] Caching finalized
>   dependency graph completed, took 450ms [SEVERE] Failed after 4.6s

import by itself is ok, as it works fine when I run following snippet

```
import '../.dart_tool/build/generated/buildertest/lib/environment.g.dart';


void main() {

  print("Name:${Environment.name}");
  print("Endpoint:${Environment.endpoint}");
}
```

with

`dart web/main.dar`t

What should be done to make this import valid??

Here is `build.yaml`

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      angular_components|scss_builder:
        enabled: True
      env|builder:
        options:
          name: "default"
          endpoint: "http://example.org"
        enabled: true

builders:
  env|builder:
    import: "env/EnvBuilder.dart"
    builder_factories: ["builderFactory"]
    is_optional: false
    build_extensions:
      "$lib$": ["environment.g.dart"]
    auto_apply: root_package
    runs_before: ["build_test:test_bootstrap","build_modules:module_library","build_modules:dartdevc","build_web_compilers:ddc","build_modules:vm","build_modules:dart2js","build_web_compilers:entrypoint"]
```